# Repetitive task entering key/values in to languages files

Tags: codeigniter, automation

I have a code igniter application which is in 3 languages. When I have a new key/value pair for a language entry, I do the following:

1. define key/value in english
2. Go to google translate for other 2 languages
3. add key/value to other files

This takes about 2-3 minutes per key. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this up? Are their APIS for google translate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_translate.html

This is the docs for the current iteration of the translate REST API

In theory you could probably write an application that would take an english lang file and generate it into a specified language.  Seems it would be very useful/popular.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think technically this idea violates their terms of use. Specifically: "We highly encourage you to include the userip parameter (not required, but highly encouraged). This parameter supplies the IP address of the end-user who made the request and validates that you are not making automated requests in violation of the Terms of Service."

Comment: I am manually running the queries just when I need to translate, it has worked great.

Comment: my idea is that so the developer **is** the end user and generates the lang files once.